# Why are there different Lemmatizers in NLTK library?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, lemmatization

```
>> from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer as lm1
>> from nltk import WordNetLemmatizer as lm2
>> from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer as lm3
```

For me all of the three works the same way, but just to confirm, do they provide anything different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No they're not different they're all the same.

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer as lm1
from nltk import WordNetLemmatizer as lm2
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer as lm3

lm1 == lm2 
>>> True


lm2 == lm3 
>>> True


lm1 == lm3 
>>> True
```

As corrected by [erip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2883245/erip) why this is happening is because :

That Class(`WordNetLemmatizer`) is origanlly written in [nltk.stem.wordnet](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/stem/wordnet.py#L15) so you can do `from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer as lm3`

Which is also import in nltk [__init__.py file](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/__init__.py#L137) so you can do `from nltk import WordNetLemmatizer as lm2`

And is also imported in [__init__.py nltk.stem](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/stem/__init__.py#L30) module so you can do `from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer as lm1`

Comment: Your last point is incorrect. NLTK uses `__init__.py` to hide this. Has nothing to do with the efficiency of the language's importing mechanism. See [here](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/__init__.py#L137), [here](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/stem/__init__.py#L30), and [here](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/stem/wordnet.py#L15).

Answer (score 2):

**Answer:** They are all the same.

[`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) helpful tool to check whether objects are the same

```
>>> import inspect
>>> from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer as wnl1
>>> from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer as wnl2
>>> inspect.getfile(wnl1)
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/stem/wordnet.pyc'
# They come from the same file:
>>> inspect.getfile(wnl1) == inspect.getfile(wnl2)
True
>>> print inspect.getdoc(wnl1)
WordNet Lemmatizer

Lemmatize using WordNet's built-in morphy function.
Returns the input word unchanged if it cannot be found in WordNet.

    >>> from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
    >>> wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
    >>> print(wnl.lemmatize('dogs'))
    dog
    >>> print(wnl.lemmatize('churches'))
    church
    >>> print(wnl.lemmatize('aardwolves'))
    aardwolf
    >>> print(wnl.lemmatize('abaci'))
    abacus
    >>> print(wnl.lemmatize('hardrock'))
    hardrock
```

You can check the source code too:

```
>>> print inspect.getsource(wnl1)
class WordNetLemmatizer(object):
    """
    WordNet Lemmatizer

    Lemmatize using WordNet's built-in morphy function.
    Returns the input word unchanged if it cannot be found in WordNet.

        >>> from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
        >>> wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
        >>> print(wnl.lemmatize('dogs'))
        dog
        >>> print(wnl.lemmatize('churches'))
        church
        >>> print(wnl.lemmatize('aardwolves'))
        aardwolf
        >>> print(wnl.lemmatize('abaci'))
        abacus
        >>> print(wnl.lemmatize('hardrock'))
        hardrock
    """

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def lemmatize(self, word, pos=NOUN):
        lemmas = wordnet._morphy(word, pos)
        return min(lemmas, key=len) if lemmas else word

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<WordNetLemmatizer>'

# They have the same source code too:
>>> print inspect.getsource(wnl1) == inspect.getsource(wnl2)
True
```

The structure of the imports in NLTK for the `WordNetLemmatizer` looks like this:

```
\nltk
    __init__.py
    \stem.
        __init__.py  
        wordnet.py     # This is where WordNetLemmatizer code resides.
```

We start from the lowest where `WordNetLemmatizer` resides in `nltk.stem.wordnet.py` https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/stem/wordnet.py#L15, so you can do:

```
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
```

From nltk.stem.**init**.py, we see the above import at [https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/stem/**init**.py#L30](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/stem/__init__.py#L30) that allows `nltk.stem` to access WordNetLemmatizer, so that you can do

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
```

From `nltk.__init__.py` we see:

```
from nltk.stem import *
```

That allows the topmost level `nltk` import to access everything that `nltk.stem` have access to. So at the top level `nltk`, we can do:

```
from nltk import WordNetLemmatizer
```

---

One thing to note though, it's **NOT** always the case that the objects/modules with the same name refers to the same object in NLTK, e.g.:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn1
>>> from nltk.corpus.reader import wordnet as wn2
>>> wn1 == wn2
False

>>> wn1.synsets('dog')
[Synset('dog.n.01'), Synset('frump.n.01'), Synset('dog.n.03'), Synset('cad.n.01'), Synset('frank.n.02'), Synset('pawl.n.01'), Synset('andiron.n.01'), Synset('chase.v.01')]

>>> wn2.synsets('dog')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'synsets'
```

The first wordnet `wn1` is a `LazyCorpusLoader` object that will open the wordnet files in `nltk_data` and it allows you to access the synsets: [https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/**init**.py#L246](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/__init__.py#L246)

The second `wn2` is the `wordnet.py` file itself that resides in `nltk.corpus.wordnet.py`: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py

It gets even more tricky when:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn1
>>> from nltk.corpus.reader import wordnet as wn2
>>> from nltk.stem import wordnet as wn3
>>> wn3 == wn1
False
>>> wn3 == wn2
False
```

In the case of `wn3`, it is referring to the file `nltk.stem.wordnet.py` that contains the `WordNetLemmatizer` and it has nothing to do with the wordnet corpus object or corpus reader for wordnet.